# Disabled checkbox enable when an input box focused

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do I do this, when any input field focused then disabled checkbox is enabled?

Here is my code (HTML):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
       <body>

          <form action="#">
          User name:<br>
          <input type="text" name="name">
          <br>
          User password:<br>
          <input type="password" id="password" name="password">

          <input type="checkbox" name="email_login_details" id="email_login_details" value="Car">Email login details

<!-- Note: I want firstly disabled this checkbox. When I type password then enable this checkbox. -->

          </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#password").change(function () {
            var password = $('#password').val();
            if ($(password)) {
                $("#email_login_details").removeClass("disabled");
            } else {
                $("#email_login_details").addClass("disabled");
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

below is a working example of what you have asked for with some enhancement of an edge case

```js
$("#password").change(function() {
  let password = $("#password").val()
  console.log(password);
  if (password) {
    console.log()
    $("#email_login_details").removeAttr("disabled");
  } else {
    $("#email_login_details").prop("checked", false);
    $("#email_login_details").attr("disabled", "true");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#">
  User name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="name">
  <br> User password:<br>
  <input type="password" id="password" name="password">

  <input type="checkbox" name="email_login_details" id="email_login_details" value="Car" disabled>Email login details

  <!-- Note: I want firstly disabled this checkbox. When I type password then enable this checkbox. -->

</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use JQuery's [`focus`](https://api.jquery.com/focus/) event handler.

```js
$("input").focus(function () {

console.log('enabling checkbox');

$('#email_login_details').removeAttr('disabled');

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="#">
User name:<br>
<input type="text" name="name">
<br>
User password:<br>
<input type="password" id="password" name="password">

<input type="checkbox" name="email_login_details" id="email_login_details" value="Car" disabled>Email login details

<!-- Note: I want firstly disabled this checkbox. When I type password then enable this checkbox. -->

</form>
</body>
</html>
```